# I want to stop execution inside if else without having any loop. How to do it without using functions?

Tags: python

In the following code, the comment shows the position where I want to stop the execution.

```
about_pet=input("Enter a sentence about pet: ")
if 'dog' in about_pet:
    if not 'cat' in about_pet:
        print("Ah, a dog")
    elif 'cat' in about_pet:
        print('Dog and Cat')
        # I want to stop execution here.
if 'cat' in about_pet:
    print('Meow!! Meow!!')
```

[output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vdvq.png)

I have tried this:

```
import sys
about_pet=input("Enter a sentence about pet: ")
if 'dog' in about_pet:
    if not 'cat' in about_pet:
        print("Ah, a dog")
    elif 'cat' in about_pet:
        print('Dog and Cat')
        exit()
if 'cat' in about_pet:
    print('Meow!! Meow!!')
```

But the above code stops the kernel and it gets restarted on clicking ok.
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nRSd.png)

The break condition is showing error that it's not inside loop.

Comment: Replace the last `if` by an `elif`.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:** To exit the script you can start by replacing the conditional structure:

```
import sys
about_pet=input("Enter a sentence about pet: ")
if 'dog' in about_pet:
    if not 'cat' in about_pet:
        print("Ah, a dog")
    elif 'cat' in about_pet:
        print('Dog and Cat')
elif 'cat' in about_pet:
    print('Meow!! Meow!!')
```

The conditional statements can also look something like:

```
if ('dog' in about_pet) & (not 'cat' in about_pet):
    print("Ah, a dog")
elif ('dog' in about_pet) & ('cat' in about_pet):
    print('Dog and Cat')
else:
    print('Meow!! Meow!!')
```

**Approach 2:** You can try returning an integer from the `exit()` function - 0 means success.

```
sys.exit(0)
```

**Approach 3:** There is also another dirty approach which can work (wouldn't really use it this approach but its another possible solution) - raising an exception

```
raise Exception('Cat is in about_pet')
```

Comment: The approach 2 is stopping the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a boolean variable or to modify the if statement.

```
pet_found = False
about_pet=input("Enter a sentence about pet: ")
if 'dog' in about_pet:
    if not 'cat' in about_pet:
        print("Ah, a dog")
    elif 'cat' in about_pet:
        print('Dog and Cat')
        pet_found = True
        # I want to stop execution here.
if not pet_found and 'cat' in about_pet:
    print('Meow!! Meow!!')
```

For this specific example, modifying if is better because it makes the code more human readable.

```
about_pet=input("Enter a sentence about pet: ")
if 'dog' in about_pet and 'cat' in about_pet:
    print('Dog and Cat')
elif 'cat' in about_pet:
    print('Meow!! Meow!!')
elif 'dog' in about_pet:
    print("Ah, a dog")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works..!!!

```
about_pet=input("Enter a sentence about pet: ")
if 'dog' in about_pet:
    if not 'cat' in about_pet:
        print("Ah, a dog")
    elif 'cat' in about_pet:
        print('Dog and Cat')

elif 'cat' in about_pet:
    print('Meow!! Meow!!')
```

if "cat" is entered,

```
Enter a sentence about pet: cat
Meow!! Meow!!
```

if "dog" is entered,

```
Enter a sentence about pet: dog
Ah, a dog
```

if "cat and dog" is entered,

```
Enter a sentence about pet: cat and dog
Dog and Cat
```

Comment: You should add output as well. It will be easy to understand for others.

Comment: @AnshulVyas Thank you for your suggestion bro.